# Why a promise is not always fulfilled, although it has the same parameters (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have an Object as follow:

```
let myObj ={
    doSomething:(path, fileName)=>{
        myObj.readFile(path, fileName).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        })
    }, //doSomething
    readFile:(path, fileName)=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile(path.join(p, f), { encoding: "utf8", flag: "r" }, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error(err.message);
                }
                console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            })//fs.readFile-callback
        });// return
    }//readFile
} //myOb
```

**The Problem**

I can read a file directly using this line of code: `myObj.readFile('path/to/file','fileName').then((data)=>{console.log(data);})`

However, when I try to read exactly the same file within the `myObj.doSomething('path/to/file','fileName').then((data)=>{console.log(data);})`

I get an Error Message: *Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*

I cannot understand what is the hack here?
Please note, that I am trying to write this object `myObj`, to analyse some files (HTML, CSS, JS).

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: i mean... in one case you returned a promise, in the other you returned nothing... it isn't unexpected for the other to then not have a .then method in the returned `undefined` value.

Comment: you need to do `return myObj.readFile`

Comment: Thats because  in your second example you haven't read the file yet. The object doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the promise:

```
doSomething:(path, fileName)=>{
    return myObj.readFile(path, fileName);
}, //doSomething
```

And by the way, you should reject and not throw:

```
if (err) {
   reject(err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this post, actually the whole vote is downvoted, not your answer :´( 

On other hand. I threw an error and NOT rejected it, because, and as you know probably , if you chained promises, the error will be caught by the `catch()` at the end of the promise-chain

Comment: @user2804070 it is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

myObj.doSomething is a function which does not return a promise, so you can't possibly call then on it.

Comment: you're right, I had to delete the `then()` call, thus the function call should look like: `myObj.doSomething('path/to/file','fileName')`.